# Generating XML without a fixed schema in the form of a nested list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an XML file which I need to return from the controller and display the XML in the view in such a way that it will be in the form of a nested list. I also need control over this list like selection and clicks to move to other pages. The main problem is that all the solutions assume that I would have a fixed schema, but my schema can change over time and cannot bind it to a model. How can I parse the XML in view and generate the list dynamically ?

Comment: Have you considered using reflection?

Comment: I have read about it, but how do i go about it ? I tried using ExpandoObject but there too u need to know about the properties, ie the xml elements which will be put in the properties. Can u point me in the right direction if u know something specific ?